# How to create a compressed dmg file using Linux tools?

Tags: linux, compression, dmg

There are a lots of question teaching how to create a DMG file from Linux. But none of them is clear about how to add compression to it.

I usually create a DMG package to redistribute to MacOS, but I would like to add compression as Apple specifies.

Did anyone have a chance to try a tool that supports compression during DMG packing?

Similar questions without compression:

- [How can I generate a DMG file from a folder in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524056/how-can-i-generate-a-dmg-file-from-a-folder-in-linux)
- [How to create dmg file in Centos through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910347/how-to-create-dmg-file-in-centos-through-command-line)

Comment: see answer from 'uckelman' at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Here is a [good analysis of the .dmg format](http://newosxbook.com/DMG.html). From that document, the compression is specified for each block chunk:

```
Table: DMG blxx types
Type    Scheme  Meaning
0x00000000  --- Zero-Fill
0x00000001  UDRW/UDRO   RAW or NULL compression (uncompressed)
0x00000002  --- Ignored/unknown
0x80000004  UDCO    Apple Data Compression (ADC)
0x80000005  UDZO    zLib data compression
0x80000006  UDBZ    bz2lib data compression
0x7ffffffe  --- No blocks - Comment: +beg and +end
0xffffffff  --- No blocks - Identifies last blxx entry
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the gist of @Valerio's comment into a proper answer so nobody else misses it like I almost did:

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553878/435253) by @uckelman:

1. instal [libdmg-hfsplus](https://github.com/fanquake/libdmg-hfsplus)
2. Run `dmg uncompressed.dmg compressed.dmg`